# lualatex: change font for specific characters (IPA) [U+0250 , U+02AF] globally

Tags: fonts, luatex

Im using lualatex.
My tex file contains the character ɛ as well as:

```tex
\newfontfamily\ipafont{Doulos SIL}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textipafont}{\ipafont}
```

Now I can do s.t. like:

```tex
\textipafont{ɛ}
```

to render that char correctly.

But: How can I define globally that all chars within [ U+0250 , U+02AF ] are surrounded by \textipafont?

The best case would be: I type ɛ and latex changes automatically the font to Doulos SIL for that character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the chars active and give them a definition:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\ipafont{Doulos SIL}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textipafont}{\ipafont}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ɛ}{\textipafont{ɛ}}
\begin{document}
abc ɛ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also define the font as a fallback (the color is only there for the demo). It is a bit experimental, see the luaotfload documentation for details

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua
{luaotfload.add_fallback
 ("ipafallback",
  {
   "DoulosSIL:mode=node;color=FF0000;"
  }
 )
}

\directlua
{luaotfload.add_fallback
 ("ipafallbackslanted",
  {
   "DoulosSIL:mode=node;slant=0.2;color=FF0000;"
  }
 )
}



\setmainfont{LatinModernRoman}[%
 RawFeature={fallback=ipafallback},
 ItalicFeatures={RawFeature={fallback=ipafallbackslanted}}
 ]

\begin{document} 

blub hɛˈləʊ wɜːld

\large blub hɛˈləʊ wɜːld

\itshape blub hɛˈləʊ wɜːld

\end{document}
```

[image]